# How to change euler to Quaternion?

Tags: animation, rigging

I found out my problem. I didn't change XYZ Euler to Quaternion.

[image]

It is easy to do it when you use Rigify to rig your character.
However, I use "Auto-Rig Pro" to rig my character.

[image]

I don't know there is any way to fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can open your file with Blender 2.91 and use the Rigify Quat/Euler converter, which works on any rig, and I hope it will be reintegrated in newer Blender version also (I discovered yesterday that it was missing from 2.93 and 2.92).

Be careful because ARPro can go crazy when edited (it doesn't allow visual keyframing, constraints on control bones, baking of animations and others advanced stuff).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You're welcome, please mark the answer as accepted if useful.

Comment: "Be careful because ARPro can go crazy when edited (it doesn't allow visual keyframing, constraints on control bones, baking of animations and others advanced stuff)."
Not sure what you are talking about? Works great here...

Comment: Probably it got fixed. Back in 2021 it had thoose kind of problems.